# Uncaught TypeError: (((item.value + 1) / total) * 100).floor is not a function

Tags: javascript, math, svg, graph, typeerror

This code is running good here: https://jsfiddle.net/petersirka/fycx4kr1/
but not on other code editor like codepen or vscode getting error on line 33

```
//HTML
<svg id="svg" width="600" height="600"></svg>

//Javascript

function Donut(cx, cy, radius, data) {

  function arcradius(cx, cy, radius, degrees) {`enter code here`
    var radians = (degrees - 90) * Math.PI / 180.0;
    return {
      x: cx + (radius * Math.cos(radians)),
      y: cy + (radius * Math.sin(radians))
    };
  }

  var decimals = 4;
  var total = 0;
  var arr = [];
  var beg = 0;
  var end = 0;
  var count = 0;

  var half = radius / 2;
  var midpoint = radius / 2.4;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    total += data[i].value;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var item = data[i];
    var tmp = {};

    var p = (((item.value + 1) / total) * 100).floor(2);

    count += p;

    if (i === length - 1 && count < 100)
      p = p + (100 - count);

    end = beg + ((360 / 100) * p);
    tmp.index = i;
    tmp.value = item.value;
    tmp.data = item;

    var b = arcradius(cx, cy, radius, end);
    var e = arcradius(cx, cy, radius, beg);
    var la = (end - beg) <= 180 ? 0 : 1;

    tmp.d = ['M', b.x.floor(decimals), b.y.floor(decimals), 'A', radius, radius, 0, la, 0, e.x.floor(decimals), e.y.floor(decimals)].join(' ');
    arr.push(tmp);
    beg = end;
  }

  return arr;
}

// USAGE
(function(svg) {

  var data = [{
    value: 45
  }, {
    value: 25
  }, {
    value: 30
  }];
  var centerX = 300;
  var centerY = 300;
  var radius = 250;
  var color = ['#7400b8', '#ff006e', '#3a86ff'];

  var arr = Donut(centerX, centerY, radius, data);
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var item = arr[i];
    svg.asvg('<g><path d="{0}" stroke="{1}" fill="none" stroke-width="50" /></g>'.format(item.d, color[i]));
  }

})(document.getElementById('#svg'));
```

I know Math.Floor is a function because I've used it before and I looked it up. Did I mess something up in the code? Thanks.
Sorry if this question is a little vague, I'm still learning (as you can see :p).

Comment: looks like jsfiddle have a Number.prototype.floor method which is not standard. Just replace those floor() calls with Math.floor() ones

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the line

> var p = (((item.value + 1) / total) * 100).floor(2);

into an integer with the floor function, you must write it like this:

var p = Math.floor(((item.value + 1) / total) * 100);

So the term you want to apply the Math.floor() function is inside the brackets.

I don't know what that (2) at the end means though...